# Trying to read the full XML file as a String in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, file

I am trying to read the whole XML file in Java. Below is my XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <app hash='nv', name='Tech', package = '1.0', version='13', filesize='200', create_date='01-03-1987', upate_date='07-09-2013' >
            <url>
                <name>RJ</name>
                <score>10</score>
            </url>
            <url>
                <name>ABC</name>
                <score>20</score>
            </url>
        </app>
```

And below is my code, I am using to read the full XML file as shown above and then get hash, name, package etc value from that XML file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    File fXmlFile = new File("C:\\ResourceFile\\app.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    System.out.println(doc);

} catch (Exception e) {

}
}
```

And as soon as I am running the above program. I am always getting the below excpetion-

```
[Fatal Error] app.xml:2:22: Element type "app" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: If you really just want it as a string, why are you running it through an XML parser?

Comment: Why *attributes* are delimited by *comma*?

Comment: @Matt, I was not sure how should I do that so I thought let's do it through XML parser. Any other ideas?

Comment: @AVD, How it should look like in general? I made up that XML file by my own as my colleague asked me to do that. Any idea how it should look like?

Comment: read it as a file, with a bufferedReader and put the buffer into and stringbuilder, and then toString();

Comment: as @AVD said, the only reason it's not working is because you have commas all over the place.  remove them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is syntax error in your xml. The attributes of the element  should not be separated by a comma. It should be like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app hash='nv' name='Tech' package='1.0' version='13' filesize='200' create_date='01-03-1987' upate_date='07-09-2013' >
    <url>
        <name>RJ</name>
        <score>10</score>
    </url>
    <url>
        <name>ABC</name>
        <score>20</score>
    </url>
</app>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to parse it as `XML` and only to show as a String maybe you want to use 
a `BufferedReader` and readLine() store it in a `StringBuilder` and then show it. [How to read a file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)

Example:

```
   public String readFile(String path) throws IOException{
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))){

        while ((String sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(sCurrentLine);
        }

    }

          return sb.toString();
    }
```

**EDIT** In java 8 you can just simply use

```
String xml = Files.lines(Paths.getPath(path)).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: but it doesn't respect the `<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>` line of the file.

Comment: Not Path, it must be Paths class.

Comment: @SemihOkanPehlivan fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    InputStream is = getAssets().open("HeadWork_JackWell.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder= dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc= dBuilder.parse(is);
    try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));
     String s=sw.toString();
     System.out.println(s);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error converting to String", ex);
    }
```